# QGIS map tip / label showing a table

Tags: qgis, labeling, sql-server, display

I have a MSSQQL Spatiatal layer with Point data (borehole locations, pointID) and a joint table lithology (soil info per borehole, pointID, depth from, depth to, constituent)

Is there a way to use the html map tip display to output a small table like this?

```
Depth from/      depth to/     constituent/ 
0/               1/            sand
1/               2/            clay
2/               3/            gravel
```

I manage to get the 3 columns but get only one row showing the last existing Lithology row for the chosen pointID ... goal is to see all existing rows for a specific pointID.

Any ideas??

Comment: Map tips are for 1 feature - I'm not sure how you're going to display more rows than the single feature you're hovering over...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try html annotations?  There are some open questions about getting them to reliably take data from the object under the annotation object - I wasn't able to, and it doesn't seem like the author has prioritized it; but depending on your use case, it may be a good workaround to just create the static html (without placeholders) externally using a python script or such, then point the annotation to that static html file.  I also noticed that the html files are re-read at project load time, so, if you can make your annotation and point to a certain filename, you may be able to leave it that way: to recalculate, run the script externally to generate the html files, then reload the project.
Curious to hear if this fits your needs. Good luck.